# Erlang - Is it possible to limit the ram consumption when using disc copies in Mnesia?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have a 4GB ram in my system and it used 2GB of ram before the insertion completed wen using disc_copies. I was wondering what would happen if 100 percent of the ram was consumed? Is there any option to limit the ram consumed during disc_copies, like limiting the ram usage to 2GB?

Comment: 2GB with _which_ metric. May be it just buffered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking how to limit erlang VM memory usage you should use [control groups](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125024/10710) for it. But if you like to monitor memory usage you should use [memory monitor `memsup`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/memsup.html) from [`os_mon` application](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/os_mon_app.html).

```
$ erl -boot start_sasl
Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

...    
=PROGRESS REPORT==== 22-Oct-2015::22:39:46 ===
         application: sasl
          started_at: nonode@nohost
Eshell V7.0  (abort with ^G)
1> application:start(os_mon).
...    
=PROGRESS REPORT==== 22-Oct-2015::22:40:03 ===
         application: os_mon
          started_at: nonode@nohost
ok
2> 
...
2> memsup:get_memory_data().
{8162500608,6514708480,{<0.7.0>,426616}}
3> memsup:get_system_memory_data().
[{system_total_memory,8162500608},
 {free_swap,5996748800},
 {total_swap,5997850624},
 {cached_memory,3290759168},
 {buffered_memory,444370944},
 {free_memory,1647222784},
 {total_memory,8162500608}]
4>
```

Read `os_mon` documentation about usage and alarms.